# Webpack and PostCSS Autoprefixer not compiling Sass partials

Tags: webpack, sass, postcss, autoprefixer, extracttextwebpackplugin

I'm using Webpack to compile Sass and the PostCSS autoprefixer is not working on partials being imported into the `style.scss` entry point.

Adding styles directly to `style.scss` are being prefixed as expected, yet any file referenced as an `@import` is not being autoprefixed.

I have added webpack.config, postcss.config and style.scss for reference below.

**webpack.config.js**

```
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: ['./src/js/index.js', './src/scss/style.scss'], 
    output: {
        filename: './js/bundle.js',
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        publicPath: './dist/'
    },
    watch: true,
    module: {
        loaders: [
        {
            test: /.jsx?$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            query: {
                presets: ['es2015', 'react']
            }
        },
        {
            test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: 'url-loader',
                    options: {}  
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                fallback: "style-loader",
                use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader', 'postcss-loader']
            }),
            exclude: /node_modules/,
        }
    ]},

    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin({ filename: './css/style.css' })
    ]

};
```

**postcss.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  map: false,
  plugins: {
    'autoprefixer': {browsers: ['last 2 versions', '> 5%']},
  }
}
```

**style.scss**

```
@import url('//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');
@import 'partials/admin'; 
@import 'partials/nav';
@import 'partials/photos';  
@import 'partials/no-results';  
.test{
   display: flex; // <- This is being prefixed as expected.
}
```

Is there a special loader or syntax I am missing get the `@import` files autoprefixed?

*** EDIT ***

I was able to solve this by adjusting the order of the scss loaders.

```
{
test: /\.scss$/,
use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
    fallback: "style-loader",
    use: [
     { loader: 'css-loader' },
     { loader: 'postcss-loader' },
     { loader: 'sass-loader', 
        options: {
           outputStyle: 'expanded'
        },
     }
   ]
}),
exclude: /node_modules/,
}
```

Comment: yes, ordering matters. loaders in Webpack are like transforming tools. one loader's output is next loader's input.

Comment: you should put your * EDIT * as an answer and mark it correct. worked for me as well

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try [postcss-scss](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-scss)

I further provide a postcss.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
parser: 'postcss-scss',
plugins: [
    require('autoprefixer'),
]
}
```

Good luck

Comment: This module does not compile SCSS.